# jQuery not working in background.js of chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension. Here is my manifest:

```
                {
            "manifest_version": 2,
            "name": "ROBLOX-R",
            "version": "1",
            "description": "An extension to automatically trade currencies.",
            "browser_action": {
                "default_icon": "icon.png",
                "default_popup": "popup.html"
                },
            "permissions": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "content_scripts": [{
                "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
                "js": [ "jquery.min.js" ]
            }],
            "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] }
            }
```

Jquery.min.js does not load for use into background.js. I know this because if I go to the background page of my script while it's running, it says, "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined". How do I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `content_scripts` property is intended to link scripts and stylesheets that will be injected in the context of webpage where your extension will be active. if you want to use the jQuery in the background page, you should add the `jquery.min.js` to the `scripts` property of the `background`:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery.min.js", "background.js"]
}
```

Hope it helps.